# Как добавить random через stream

Tags: java, java-stream

Можно ли сюда добавить random через stream ?

```
questionNoAnswer.setTags(tagList.stream().limit(5).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: Куда конкретно? Можно куда угодно.

Comment: `tagList.stream().limit(5).collect(Collectors.toList())` ну вот сюда чтобы теги записались рандомно а не по порядку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему

`questionNoAnswer.setTags(new Random().ints(5, 0, tagList.size()) .mapToObj(c -> tagList.get(c)) .collect(Collectors.toList()))`